# Standard way to communicate with Linux driver?

Tags: c, linux, architecture, driver, hardware

I wrote a driver for custom USB device (in `C`) and made it accessible via shared memory. For example, I can communicate with this driver from within `PHP` inside of my web-application with `shmop_*` functions. It works but I wonder: are there more standard ways to design API with a driver? May be I should implement device files or something?

Suppose I have some memory on board of my device, which shows it's status and a set of commands, which I can send to it via USB. What is the most "linuxish" way to design communication with the driver of such device?

Comment: See §7 at https://tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.4/html/book1.htm

Comment: read/write for data. sysfs for control and status.